# Select Top 1 From a Table For Each row in another Table

Tags: openedge, cross-apply

I am just starting to work with openedge and I need to join information from two tables but I just need the first row from the second one.

Basically I need to do a typical SQL Cross Apply but in progress. I look in the documentation and the Statement `FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS ONLY` only in OpenEdge 11.

My query is:

```
SELECT * FROM la_of PUB.la_ofart ON la_of.empr_cod = la_ofart.empr_cod 
  AND la_of.Cod_Ordf = la_ofart.Cod_Ordf 
  AND la_of.Num_ordex = la_ofart.Num_ordex AND la_of.Num_partida = la_ofart.Num_partida
  CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 ofart.Cod_Ordf AS Cod_Ordf_ofart , 
              ofart.Num_ordex AS Num_ordex_ofart
    FROM la_ofart AS ofart
    WHERE ofart.empr_cod = la_ofart.empr_cod 
        AND ofart.Num_partida = la_ofart.Num_partida 
        AND la_ofart.doc1_num = ofart.doc1_num 
        AND la_ofart.doc2_linha = ofart.doc2_linha
    ORDER BY ofart.Cod_Ordf DESC) ofart
```

I am using SSMS to extract data from OE10 using an ODBC connector and querying to OE using OpenQuery.

Thanks for all help.

Comment: Is your problem that FETCH FIRST is in OE11 but you are running something older and therefore cannot use it?

Comment: Hi @Tom Bascom ,  

I can not have function or a process to emulate a Cross Apply in OE. The version I have to work is OE10.2. I look in internet and for what I read if I had OE 11 my problem could be solved with FETCH FIRST. 

But because I have to use OE10 I need a workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I correctly understood your question, maybe you can use something like this. Maybe this isn't the best solution for your problem, but may suit your needs.

```
DEF BUFFER ofart    FOR la_ofart.

DEF TEMP-TABLE tt-ofart NO-UNDO LIKE ofart
    FIELD seq       AS INT
    INDEX ch-seq
        seq.

DEF VAR i-count     AS INT  NO-UNDO.

EMPTY TEMP-TABLE tt-ofart.

blk:
FOR EACH la_ofart NO-LOCK,
    EACH la_of NO-LOCK  
        WHERE la_of.empr_cod    = la_ofart.empr_cod
        AND   la_of.Cod_Ordf    = la_ofart.Cod_Ordf
        AND   la_of.Num_ordex   = la_ofart.Num_ordex 
        AND   la_of.Num_partida = la_ofart.Num_partida,
    EACH ofart NO-LOCK
        WHERE ofart.empr_cod    = la_ofart.empr_cod
        AND   ofart.Num_partida = la_ofart.Num_partida
        AND   ofart.doc1_num    = la_ofart.doc1_num
        AND   ofart.doc2_linha  = la_ofart.doc2_linha
    BREAK BY ofart.Cod_Ordf DESCENDING:

    ASSIGN i-count = i-count + 1.

    CREATE tt-ofart.
    BUFFER-COPY ofart TO tt-ofart
        ASSIGN ofart.seq = i-count.

    IF i-count >= 10 THEN
        LEAVE blk.

END.

FOR EACH tt-ofart USE-INDEX seq:
    DISP tt-ofart WITH SCROLLABLE 1 COL 1 DOWN NO-ERROR.
END.
```

Comment: Hi @Bruno, I really did not explain me very well... I am using SSMS to extract data from OE10 using an ODBC conector and quering to OE using OpenQuery. I am trying to avoid export massive data to my side. I am going to edit my question adding this information.